# PHP Foreach only get one data

Tags: php, foreach, codeigniter-3

i want to loop all the data i call but that runs only one data
I use Codeigniter framework

Model:

`$this->db->where('group_user', 'upt_perpus')->order_by('idmodul', 'DESC')->get('menu')->result_array();`

Controller:

```
  $data = array(
     'about' => array(
        'sejarah' => 'Sejarah',
        'visi_misi' => 'Visi, Misi & Tujuan',
        'struktur' => 'Struktur Organisasi'
     ),
     'services' => array(),
     'peraturan' => array(
        'umum' => 'Umum',
        'khusus' => 'Khusus',
        'pelayanan_perpus' => 'Pelayanan Perpustakaan'
     )
  );
  $konten = $this->kontens->getPerpus();
  foreach ($konten as $key) {
     $data['services'] = array(
        $key['slug'] => $key['judul']
     );
  }
  return $data;
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$data['services']` every time through the loop, not collecting them into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an associative array in `$data['services']`, you need to assign to a key of the array.

```
  foreach ($konten as $key) {
     $data['services'][$key['slug']] = $key['judul'];
  }
```